# Edit A Single Item and save formers data (FlatList)

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm trying to make a "like" system as you can see on instagram -> when i press the heart it becomes red and full, and if I press it again it becomes again black and with outline. When I Press one heart other must stay with their actual style
, but I'm encountering this error.  : initializeAnArray is not a function... Please can you help me.
If maybe you have a better way to code what i'am trying to do I don't refuse your tips. Thank You

```
    const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    message: "Hi",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    message: "Hello",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    message: "Welcome",
  },
];

function Heart(props) {
  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState(data);
  const [heart, setHeart] = useState(initializeAnArray("heart-outline"));
  const [heartColor, setHeartColor] = useState(initializeAnArray("black"));
  const [getIndex, setGetIndex] = useState(-1);

  const initializeAnArray = (value) => {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataUser.length; i++) {
      newArray.push(value);
    }
    return newArray;
  };

  const editArray = (array, id, value) => {
    array[id] = value;
    return array;
  };

  const heartPress = (id) => {
    setGetIndex(id);
    if ((id = getIndex)) {
      heartColor[id] === "red"
        ? setHeartColor(editArray(heartColor, id, "black")) +
          setHeart(editArray(heart, id, "heart-outline"))
        : setHeartColor(editArray(heartColor, id, "red")) +
          setHeart(editArray(heart, id, "heart-outline"));
    }
    setHeartColor(editArray(heartColor, id, heartColor[id]));
    setHeart(editArray(heart, id, heart[id]));
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <FlatList
        data={dataUser}
        extraData={dataUser}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.message}>
              <Text>{item.message}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={heartPress(parseInt(item.id) - 1)}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name={heart[parseInt(item.id) - 1]}
                  size={12}
                  color={heartColor[parseInt(item.id) - 1]}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  message: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
export default Heart;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add `keyExtractor={item => item.id}` to your component `FlatList` and try again

something like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={dataUser}
    extraData={dataUser}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.message}>
          <Text>{item.message}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={heartPress(parseInt(item.id) - 1)}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name={heart[parseInt(item.id) - 1]}
              size={12}
              color={heartColor[parseInt(item.id) - 1]}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't working: TypeError: InitializeAnArray is not a function...